# URL variables are not passing through URL Rewrite engine

Tags: variables, url, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to pass multiple variables through the URL Rewrite engine in IIS but I'm only getting one to pass through. The variables are: "username" and "info". At the moment I'm only getting the first variable "username" to pass through to the page.

I've tried multiple formats in URL rewrite as well as checking my syntax as well as possible but can't find anything wrong. Below is the code.

Browser friendly URL:

http://localhost/member/csaad78/social

Server-side URL:
member.asp?username=csaad78&info=social

Rule in URL rewrite engine:

```
  <rule name="member social iframe forwarded">
    <match url="^member/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="member.asp?username={R:1}&amp;info={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
    <conditions></conditions>
    <serverVariables></serverVariables>
  </rule>
```

The code catching the querystring in the page is:

member_name = Trim(request.querystring("username"))
info = Trim(request.querystring("info"))

Only the variable "username" is passing on. "info" is not being passed. I'd like to get both to pass through!

Comment: Use FRT to look closer, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below rule and asp code to get query string parameter value:

```
<rule name="member social iframe forwarded">
            <match url="^member/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/?$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="member.asp?username={R:1}&amp;info={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
```

asp code:

```
member_name= <%=Request.QueryString("username")%> info= <%= Request.QueryString("info")%>.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but I'm not sure where your code is different from mine. This doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Your urlrewrite code is working,you just need to chnage asp code which fatch the query string prameter value.  member_name= <%=Request.QueryString("username")%> info= <%= Request.QueryString("info")%>. OR    member_name= <%=Trim(Request.QueryString("username"))%> info= <%= Trim(Request.QueryString("info"))%>.

Comment: Thanks for the help!